# How to calculate distance from cluster centroids from the outputs of Matlab kmean() function

Tags: matlab, distance, k-means, centroid

I have 2 output clusters from k means matlab function
            `[idx,C] = kmeans(X,2);`

I don't know how to calculate the distance between centroid and each point in cluster by using "idx"

I want to get matrix with all points that their distance to centroid >2

```
% not Matlab code; just illustrating concept
```

example 
    c1->{x1,x2}=
    x1-c1=3
    x2-c1=2

```
c2->{y1,y2}=
y1-c2=4
y2-c2=1

output={y1,x1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

**Update** The answer now uses loops.

```
r = randn(300,2)*5;
r(151:end,:) = r(151:end,:) + 15;

n_clusters = 2;

[idx, C] = kmeans(r, n_clusters);

clusters = cell(n_clusters, 1);
distances = cell(n_clusters, 1);
for ii = 1:n_clusters
    clusters{ii} = r(idx==ii, :);
    distances{ii} = sqrt(sum((clusters{ii}-C(ii,:)).^2,2));    
end

figure;
subplot(1,2,1);   
for ii = 1:n_clusters
    plot(clusters{ii}(:,1), clusters{ii}(:,2), '.');
    hold on
    plot(C(ii,1), C(ii,2), 'ko','MarkerFaceColor', 'w');
end

title('Clusters and centroids');

subplot(1,2,2);

for ii = 1:n_clusters
    plot(clusters{ii}(distances{ii} > 2,1), clusters{ii}(distances{ii} > 2,2), '.');
    hold on
    plot(C(ii,1), C(ii,2), 'ko','MarkerFaceColor', 'w');
end
title('Centroids and points with distance > 2');
```

[image]

To get a a cell with matrices with the points larger than 2, you can do:

```
distant_points = cell(n_clusters,1);
for ii = 1:n_clusters
    distant_points{ii} = clusters{ii}(distances{ii} > 2,:)
end
```

Comment: thanks so much .it works well i am trying to do for more than cluster  in for loop  is it the best way to do  ?                                                                                              for j = 1 : 2
    cluster{j} = r(idx==j, :);
    
end                                                                                                                                   for j = 1 : 2
    distances{j} = sqrt(sum((cluster{j}-C(j,:)).^2,2));
    distant_points{j} = cluster{j}(distances{j} >0.2 ,:);

end